# Scrapy Spider returning only last element when given a list of Selectors

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I've been running into an issue with a spider I've put together. I am trying to scrape individual lines of text, along with their corresponding timestamps, from the transcript on [this site](https://www.thisamericanlife.org/radio-archives/episode/1/transcript/), and have found what I believe are the appropriate selectors, but when run, the spider's output is just the last line and timestamp. I've seen a couple others with similar issues, but haven't yet found an answer that solves my problem.

Here is the spider:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from this_american_life.items import TalTranscriptItem

class CrawlSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "transcript2"
    allowed_domains = ["https://www.thisamericanlife.org/radio-archives/episode/1/transcript"]
    start_urls = (
        'https://www.thisamericanlife.org/radio-archives/episode/1/transcript',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        item = TalTranscriptItem()
        for line in response.xpath('//p'):
            item['begin_timestamp'] = line.xpath('//@begin').extract()
            item['line_text'] = line.xpath('//text()').extract()
        yield item
```

And here is the code for `TalTranscriptItem()` in `items.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

import scrapy


class TalTranscriptItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    episode_id = scrapy.Field()
    episode_num_text = scrapy.Field()
    year = scrapy.Field()
    radio_date_text = scrapy.Field()
    radio_date_datetime = scrapy.Field()
    episode_title = scrapy.Field()
    episode_hosts = scrapy.Field()
    act_id = scrapy.Field()
    line_id = scrapy.Field()
    begin_timestamp = scrapy.Field()
    speaker_class = scrapy.Field()
    speaker_name = scrapy.Field()
    line_text = scrapy.Field()
    full_audio_link = scrapy.Field()
    transcript_url = scrapy.Field()
```

When run in the `scrapy shell`, it appears to work correctly (drawing all of the lines of text), but for some reason I haven't been able to get it to work in the spider.

I'm happy to clarify any of these issues, and would greatly appreciate any help anyone can offer!

Comment: What type is `TalTranscriptItem`?

Comment: @Hackerman     I'll add the code for TalTranscriptItem to the question. It's a class from the items.py file in the scrapy project directory.

Comment: If I recall correctly, `scrapy.Field()` is a plain old python dictionary and not a list

Comment: @Hackerman     I think you're right - are you referring to the `.append` methods in the `for` loop?

Comment: Yes, that's why it's only storing one item.

Comment: @Hackerman     Thanks for that, I was wondering if that might be part of the issue. I just changed it back to the following, and it is still only crawling the last item. Was this what you had in mind?  
`item['begin_timestamp'] = line.xpath('//@begin').extract()` I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want each individual line yielded as an item I think this is what you want (notice the last indentation for the `yield` line):

```
for line in response.css('p'):
    item = TalTranscriptItem()
    item['begin_timestamp'] = line.xpath('./@begin').extract_first()
    item['line_text'] = line.xpath('./text()').extract_first()
    yield item
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to make sense, but for some reason, it's still only returning the last item, even in the scrapy shell. Any idea why that might be? Thanks again

Comment: Could you please show how are you testing it, it works fine in my shell

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what item is but you can do:

```
item = []

for line in response.xpath('//p'):
   dictItem = {'begin_timestamp':line.xpath('//@begin').extract(),'line_text':line.xpath('//text()').extract()}
   item.append(dictItem)

print(item)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works in the scrapy shell, but for some reason, it is still only pulling the last element when run in the spider.